# How to open corrupted 7z password protected file

Tags: windows, 7-zip

I have encrypted a file using 7-Zip. When I try to open it, it is giving an error message of

```
Cannot open file "<File/Directory location>" as archive
```

I have saved my password and password is correct, but it is unable to open it. I am suspecting if it is corrupted. Please tell me how I can recover my data. It is very important.

Answer (score 0):

The file probably IS **not** corrupted.

What happens is that there is a default program to open this kind of file. You need to run **7zFM** as *administrator* so it can set the changes.